# Store usernames in array after selecting them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of usernames and filters:
[image]

If I want to add someone I check username and name goes to "Selected users" list:
[image]

But problem is if I select any filter and choose any user previous users disappear from "Selected users" list:
[image]

Here is my code to display users in the list:

```
var cloudbox = document.getElementById('cloudboxmini');
$(".fltr").click(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")){
  var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
      console.log(e.dataset.username);
    return e.dataset.username;
  });      
  cloudbox.innerHTML = "<ul><li>" + arr.join('</li><li>') + "</li></ul>";
}    
} );
```

Is there any way to save previous names as well? Maybe temporary store all selected names and then print it from there.

Comment: Can you give you html also

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store anything in Javascript. Works in all browsers natively.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may gives you any idea

```js
 $('.check').click(function(){
  html = $(this).siblings('span').html();
  if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
   var selectecd = '<tr align="center" class="'+html+'"><th>'+html+'</th></tr>';
   $('#selected').append(selectecd);
  }
  else $('.'+html).remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>
         <table align="center" width="80%" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Aa</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ba</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ca</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Da</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ea</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ab</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Bb</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Cb</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Db</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Eb</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ac</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Bc</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Cc</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Dc</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ec</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ad</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Bd</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Cd</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Dd</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ed</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ae</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Be</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ce</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>De</span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /> <span>Ee</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="20%" id="selected">
             <tr align="center"><th>Selected</th></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```